# Cancel File Upload In Google Drive API

Tags: c#, uwp, google-drive-api, task

I have code for uploading files that work on UWP. I've looked for a way to cancel the upload. Didn't find. There is a way to cancel that? I tried to add `CancellationToken` but there is no place to set this in the `DriveAPI` properties.

```cs
try
{
    StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path).AsTask().Result;
    String ID;

    var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(file.Path),
        MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
        
    };

    using (var stream = file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().Result)
    {
        

        var request = this.drive.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "application/octet-stream");


        request.ProgressChanged += (IUploadProgress progressInfo) =>
        {
            if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"done!");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
            else if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed To Upload Into Google Drive");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(progressInfo.BytesSent/(1024*1024)) + " MB has sent");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
        };

        request.ChunkSize = 262144;
        request.Upload();
        

        var uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;
        Debug.WriteLine($"File uploaded: {uploadedFile.Name} ({uploadedFile.Id})");

        ID = uploadedFile.Id;
        return ID;
    }

}
```

I tried to place `if(cancelationtoken)` in `progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Uploading` but It didn't stop the uploading. it only stops retorting to Progress.

Someone knows maybe how to dispose of the entire `Task<>`?

That's what I tried to do:

```cs
request.ProgressChanged += (IUploadProgress progressInfo) =>
        {
            if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"done!");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
            else if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed To Upload Into Google Drive");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);
            }
            else if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Uploading)
            {
                //(if(canceltoken.iscancel)...){}
                Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(progressInfo.BytesSent/(1024*1024)) + " MB has sent");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to be able to cancel a file upload and this could be made easier by making your upload method `async`. Then you would be able to make proper use of the [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator and could put the cancellation token in the upload call in this format:

`await request.UploadAsync(cancellationToken)`

---

I notice a couple of places in your code where you downgrade `async` methods to blocking calls e.g.

`StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path).AsTask().Result`

or

`var stream = file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().Result`

This somewhat defeats the purpose of those methods being asynchronous in the first place, and you may run into some deadlocks or other threading problems doing this.

---

So I would say it could be highly advantageous to reframe your method something like this:

```cs
using Metadata = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;

async Task<string> Upload(string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<IUploadProgress> prog)
{
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
    string ID;

    var fileMetadata = new Metadata()
    {
        Name = Path.GetFileName(file.Path),
        MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
    };

    using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        var request = this.drive.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "application/octet-stream");

        request.ProgressChanged += (IUploadProgress progressInfo) =>
        {
            if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"done!");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
            else if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed To Upload Into Google Drive");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(progressInfo.BytesSent / (1024 * 1024)) + " MB has sent");
                prog.Report(progressInfo);

            }
        };

        request.ChunkSize = 262144;
        await request.UploadAsync(cancellationToken);

        var uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;
        Debug.WriteLine($"File uploaded: {uploadedFile.Name} ({uploadedFile.Id})");

        ID = uploadedFile.Id;
        return ID;
    }
}
```

---

**Calling your async method**

You don't necessarily have to wait for your async method to run.  Here's an example of discarding the return value in a "fire and forget" call to the `Upload` method in a button click handler. You can also cancel a long-running upload with the second button handler.

```
CancellationTokenSource? _cts;
Progress Progress { get; } = new Progress();

void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(SpecialPath.GoogleOutbound.GetRelEnvPath(), "myUploadFile.txt");
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _ = Upload(path, _cts.Token, Progress);
}

void ButtonCancelUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: All the `async` ,`Result` and `Wait()` it was because the task stopped the UI. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Sounds like you may have gotten this figured out? Using `Result` and `Wait` will block the UI. If you need to wait for the result, but don't want to block the UI, then await the method inside an async method of your choosing. To do this kind of thing without blocking the UI, asynchronous programming is a good solution so make sure you understand it. For some of us, it really "takes something" to make that transition because, in my mind, there's a certain intuition that you pick up the more you use parallel tasks. IMO you're on the right track here.

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure how, but the UI keeps working on tasks even when I use `Result` and `Wait`. Maybe it like you said - because the tasks is `async`.
Sorry about my English..